# Netflix on Ubuntu from France

Tags: 12.04, proxy, netflix

I am a recent Ubuntu (12.04) user from France, and I'm trying to find
a way to use my Linux laptop as my main PC.

I stepped upon Erich Hoover's wonderful program "Netflix Desktop" on this
webpage http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html
.
Unfortunately, I cannot use it since ...

I'm from France and I usually use, on my windows7,"Hola Unblocker" extension for
Chrome (https://hola.org/) which I installed on firefox to try to be
able to use Netflix from this program on my ubuntu notebook.

But it doesn't work, unless I use a proxy. I don't wish to pay for a proxy in addition to netflix, but would like to use it.

Does anyone has a clue, how could I do that ?

Kind regards

Ps : I mailed the soft author which was really kind and told me he will try to look into it on the next versions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem from Spain. I also used hola unblocker when I had windows and, although I had the app on Chrome, this didn't help me because Netflix desktop uses firefox. I was able to solve the problem though by doing the following:

1. Open Netflix desktop.
2. Press ctrl + L to open the "go to" prompt
3. Go to http://www.hola.org download hola unblocker and enjoy.

Bonne chance!